# The image I add to a header doesn't appear

Tags: html, pdf, header, itext

I'm trying to create a header with an image; the header is added, but the image is missing in header. My application is deployed on an Oracle Weblogic server (using Java EE and Hibernate).

I'm trying to create the image like this. `getImage(seasonalFilter.getPictureFileId()).getAbsolutePath()`. The image path is something like this: `/tmp/6461346546165461313_65464.jpg`.

Note that I want to add text *under* the image in the header (for every page).

```
public File convertHtmlToPdf(String JSONString, ExportQueryTypeDTO queryType, String htmlText, ExportTypeDTO type) throws VedStatException {
    try {
      File retFile = null;
      FilterDTO filter = null;
      HashMap<Object, Object> properties = new HashMap<Object, Object>(queryType.getHashMap());
      filter = JSONCoder.decodeSeasonalFilterDTO(JSONString);
      DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd__HH_mm");
      //logger.debug("<<<<<<   HTML TEXT: " + htmlText + " >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
      StringBuilder tmpFileName = new StringBuilder();
      tmpFileName.append(formatter.format(new Date()));
      retFile = File.createTempFile(tmpFileName.toString(), type.getSuffix());
      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(retFile);
      com.lowagie.text.Document document = new com.lowagie.text.Document(com.lowagie.text.PageSize.LETTER);
      com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter pdfWriter = com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
      document.open();
      com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
      String str = htmlText.replaceAll("ű", "&ucirc;").replaceAll("ő", "&otilde;").replaceAll("Ő", "&Otilde;").replaceAll("Ű", "&Ucirc;");
      htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
      if (filter instanceof SeasonalFilterDTO) {
        SeasonalFilterDTO seasonalFilter = (SeasonalFilterDTO) filter;
        if (seasonalFilter.getPictureFileId() != null) {
          logger.debug("Image absolutePath: " + getImage(seasonalFilter.getPictureFileId()).getAbsolutePath());
          Image logo = Image.getInstance(getImage(seasonalFilter.getPictureFileId()).getAbsolutePath());
          logo.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
          logo.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
          logo.scalePercent(100);
          Chunk chunk = new Chunk(logo, 0, 0);
          HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(chunk), true);
          header.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
          document.setHeader(header);
        }
      }
      document.close();

      return retFile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new VedStatException(e);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Please consider adding a sample PDF missing the image. As you are using an ancient iText version (still in the com.lowagie package structure), the code may not reproduce the issue when run in a current iText environment. If you supplied the PDF we could check whether the image is in it and merely invisible or whether there is no image after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really dislike your false allegation that *"Every tutorial is based on C:\imagelocation\dsadsa.jpg"*

I'm the author of two books and many tutorials about iText and I know for a fact that what you say doesn't make any sense. Take a look at my name: "Bruno Lowagie." You are using *my* name in your code, so please believe me when I say you're doing it completely wrong.

Instead of HTMLWorker, you should use [XML Worker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html). HTMLWorker is no longer supported and will probably be removed from iText in the near future.

I see that you're also using the `HeaderFooter` class. This class has been removed several years ago. Please take a look at the newer examples: http://www.itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=221

These examples are written in Java; if you need the C# version, please look for the corresponding [C# examples in the SVN repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/).

Regarding images, you may want to read [chapter 10 of my book](http://www.itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=10).

Finally: please read http://lowagie.com/itext2

Comment: Hi Bruno, I am not downloaded, not Imported your packages into our project, we are only continuing project of other company that ended with it. We have 407 MB project (libs + code). In proj. properties iText is included in JasperReports Library. And my job is to add text and image into header of every page with existing library.

Comment: I don't see how that would be relevant. You're using an obsolete version of iText. Either you upgrade and follow the documentation, or you solve your problem on your own using the *unsupported* version. In the latter case: please don't blame the documentation. My advise: good coders write future proof code. Writing future proof code excludes using a library version that is no longer endorsed by its author.